# Add page URL to an email sent via a PHP form

Tags: php, sendmail

I'd like to add the URL of the page from where the message was sent (I have a contact form at the end of each page of my website) to the body of the e-mail generated via the code below. What should I add to the code below? (I'm a complete beginner in PHP)
Many thanks for your help

```
<?php
// Email Submit
// Note: filter_var() requires PHP >= 5.2.0
if ( isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['message']) && filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) ) {

  // detect & prevent header injections
  $test = "/(content-type|bcc:|cc:|to:)/i";
  foreach ( $_POST as $key => $val ) {
    if ( preg_match( $test, $val ) ) {
      exit;
    }
  }

  //send email
  mail( "dsfds@sfss.com", "Nouveau message de: ".$_POST['name'], $_POST['message'], "From:" . $_POST['email'] . "\r\n" . "BCC:dsfds@gmail.com" );

}
?>
```

Comment: `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` is what you want. But remember that users can spoof it if they want to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insert

```
."\nFrom site: ". $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']. $_SERVER['SCRIPT_URI']
```

after `$_POST['message']` in the last line

Comment: Unless the PHP for sending the email is repeated for each page on the site (I hope it isn't), this will always write the same thing. `HTTP_REFERER` is needed to show the page which *submitted* the form.

Comment: Thanks; I've tried this but without success. Is there a syntax error? mail( "contact@dfdsfds.com", "Nouveau message de: ".$_POST['name'], $_POST['message'] ."\nFrom site: ". $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']. $_SERVER['SCRIPT_URI'], "From:" . $_POST['email'] . "\r\n" . "BCC:dfdfds@gmail.com" );

Comment: $_SERVER['SCRIPT_URI'] is not needed if you use HTTP_REFERER. After the colons in From:, BCC: you should add a space. Without more information I can't say more. Is there any error message? Maybe in the error logs?

Answer (score 0):

Use either `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` or have a hidden post value sent with the form to identify the page or form sending the data.

Comment: Thanks; I've tried this but without success. Is there a syntax error?  mail( "contact@dfdsfds.com", "Nouveau message de: ".$_POST['name'], $_POST['message'] ."\nFrom site: ". $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']. $_SERVER['SCRIPT_URI'], "From:" . $_POST['email'] . "\r\n" . "BCC:dfdfds@gmail.com" );

Comment: Not that I can see. Try using http://phpcodechecker.com/ or from the command line: php -l somefile.php